# How to generate rows containing numbers from 0 to n in increments of m in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to generate a table with one field. The field will contain numbers from 0 to some n with increments of m. So, (0, m, 2m, 3m, ... n-m, n) 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it as an automaticly field in the mySql, or as a query/procedure that will accure single/multiple times?

Comment: I basically have one table that contains a field with different numbers in. I want to create another table that has a field with all the intervals from 0 to each of the numbers in the previous table. So, if I have 4,5,6 in the first table. I wan the resulting table to stack on top of each other (0,1,2,3,4) then on top (0...5) etc.

Comment: @NarekNersisyan . . . You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  Your question is quite different from this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive CTE to generate the numbers like below, 5 is increment and 100 is max value. may require minor changes for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) syntax, as I have written this query for SQL server.

```
WITh MyNumbers as(
Select 0 as Num
UNION all
SELECT Num + 5 as Num from MyNumbers where num <= 100
)
select * from MyNumbers
```

Comment: Your solution seems to target SQL Server but the question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: my bad, just updated my answer. Not sure about exact syntax of MySQL

Comment: MySQL 8.0 supports CTE syntax, but I expect not many people have upgraded to 8.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists counter//

-- This pocedure count from 0 -> n and insert the values to the new_table
create procedure counter(IN number1 int)
begin
    declare idx INT default 0;

    while idx <= number1 do
        insert into new_table values(idx);
        set idx = idx + 1;
    end while;
end//

drop procedure if exists mission//

-- This procedure reading a table with single field which contains numbers, and calling for each number to the procedure 'counter'
create procedure mission()
begin
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_num INT DEFAULT 0;

    -- declare cursor for all the numbers in 'TWN' table
    DEClARE num_cursor CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT TWN.number FROM TWN;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    -- Start the iterator
    open num_cursor;

    get_num: LOOP
        FETCH num_cursor INTO v_num;
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN
            -- If the procedure have been called for all the numbers
            LEAVE get_num;
        END IF;

        -- Call the procedure for the current number
        call counter(v_num);

    END LOOP get_num;

    -- Close the iterator
    CLOSE num_cursor;
end//

DELIMITER ;

-- Clear the table 'new_table' from values
truncate table new_table;

-- call the procedure 'mission'
call mission();

-- Display the results
select * from new_table;
```